# Withcount() with relationship

Tags: laravel

I have this query.
I want to bring all the posts, with their direct relations and the comment count, but I also want to add the count of a relation with survey.

```
$posts = Post::with('survey.surveyOptions', 'image', 'categories')
            ->withCount('comments')
            ->paginate(9);
```

I want to bring the count of this relationship:

```
class Survey extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function totalSurveys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option_value::class);
    }
}
```

The post model has this relationship with survey:

```
public function survey()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }
```

How can I get the totalSurveys count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing an array to with() you can add constraints to the query.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

```php
$posts = Post::with([
    'survey' => function ($query) {
        $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
    },
    'survey.surveyOptions', 
    'image', 
    'categories'
  ])
  ->withCount('comments')
  ->paginate(9);
```